# EC2 instance is out of service in loadbalancer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance up and running.
I have a load balancer where its associated with EC2 instance.

```
Ping Target         : HTTP:3001/healthCheck
Timeout             : 5 seconds
Interval            : 24 seconds
Unhealthy threshold : 2
Healthy threshold   : 10
```

[image]
Now the instance is shown as OutofService.
I even tried changing listening ports and all. Things were working until,rebooted my EC2 instance. 
Any help would be higly appreciated.

Just for the info: I have rails app running at port 3001 and I have one listenser for HTTP:80(loadbalancer) to HTTP:3001.

I also have checked the working app through ssh in the terminal.

Comment: If its OutofService, then your health check is failing.  If you can access the `/healthCheck` path directly on EC2 instance I bet you'll see a non 200 status. Perhaps after the EC2 instance was rebooted it didn't start up Rails or another service.

Comment: after rebooting, I did start rails server.. and its working fine, tested via ssh

Comment: What happens when you try to access the ec2 instance directly over http? Specifically when you access the healthCheck path?

Comment: *"Things were working until rebooted my EC2 instance."*  Did you really *reboot* the instance, or did you *stop and then start* the instance?

Comment: rebooted..(things were not fine) then stopped and started.. still same situation

Comment: @GeorgeMWhitaker I hope you are referring to public dns, Its not working..

Comment: @SunilBN I would love to help you but there isn't enough info being shared right now. Its not clear the state of any thing other than your load balancer.

Comment: What info you would need? I can provide :D

Comment: for starters, please show the security group of your EC2 instance, inbound info only. are there any logs to show for your rail server? why did it shut down abruptly? if your EC2 instance and the health check 'service' is configured correctly, then you should be able to hit that health check directly from that EC2 instance using something like `curl <local IP>:3001/healthcheck` and get an HTTP 200. if the issue is that the rail server comes up and then (for whatever reason) shuts down, then this isn't a configuration issue with the health check or security groups, it's prob with rails server.

Comment: It is not problem with rails app.i checked through ssh.. and I only had shut down the Instance. I'm blaming myself for that!

Comment: What's the output of `curl -v http://localhost:3001/healthCheck` while SSH'd on this instance?  Please add this to the question for troubleshooting.

Comment: @justderb I did run on my welcome page, it gives the webpage content.. Not error page.

Comment: Please run the curl command on the endpoint ELB is trying to hit (not your welcome page).  Like other commenters mention: you are not giving us the full picture.  Please add to your question the Security Groups on the EC2 instance and also on the ELB so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem was, after rebooting the instance aws assigns **new ip**
>   to the EC2 which I didn't notice.

And I was logging in thorough `ssh` to the old ec2 instance.
And hence curl was never failing too.

*(I am quite curious why this ip address still active and when I last checked it was active even after 15 days)*

Nevertheless great check points(in general) by [SkyWalker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2293534/skywalker).

Finally what I had to:

With new ip, my pem file also got screwed up. Hence created new instance, new pem file, adjusted load balancer to point to this instance and security groups accorindgly.

**PS:I couldn't be any more stupid.**

Answer (score 2):

### Suggestion#1:

> If the current state of some or all your instances is OutOfService and
>   the description field displays the message that the Instance has
>   failed at least the Unhealthy Threshold number of health checks
>   consecutively, the instances have failed the load balancer health
>   check.

The following are the issues to look for, the potential causes, and the steps you can take to resolve the issues by following this link: [Troubleshoot a Classic Load Balancer: Health Checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-healthcheck.html)

### Suggestion#2:

[chrisa_pm](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=364233#364233) has given some advice for this issue:

> If you can confirm that your EC2 instance is reachable, you can remove
>   it from your Load Balancer and add it back again. The Load Balancer
>   will recognize it after a few minutes though.
>
> Keep in mind that you need to confirm the health as it is set in your
>   Health Check configuration:
>
> 1. For HTTP:80 you need to specify a page that is actually reachable (like index.html)
> 2. For TCP:80 it will only be needed access to the 80 TCP port.

### Suggestion#3:

qh2 has make a solution by the following way

Create a service in startup to deregister and register again your instance.

Example: file awsloadbalancer

```
#!/bin/sh
chkconfig: 2345 95 20
```

When a isntance is stopped a load balancer is missed. this rebuild load
    balancer

```
case "$1" in
start)
aws --region eu-west-1 elb deregister-instances-from-load-balancer --load-balancer-name test --instances i-3c339b7c
aws --region eu-west-1 elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name test --instances i-3c339b7c
;;
stop)
echo "stopping aws instances"
;;
restart)
echo "Restarting aws, nothing to do"
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
exit 1
;;
esac
```

create file in `/etc/init.d/` after that, register as service.

### Suggestion#4:

[Kenneth Snyder](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/profile.jspa?userID=215128) also solved the issue for specific ELB issue.

> I also had similar issue but I was able to fix that.
>
> I had created a security group for ELB which accepts request on port
>   80 and forward to EC2 on port 80. The security group that was earlier
>   created for EC2 has also inbound rules for port 80 and RDP.
>
> Still the instances were showing as OutOfService under ELB. Later i
>   tried to add another inbound rule in the EC2's security group to allow
>   port 80 for the SG that was created for ELB. and that worked.
>
> I guess it requires the ELB SG to be allowed in the rules created for
>   individual instance's SG. Hope that helps.

### Resource Link:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=733153

Answer (score 1):

Did you provide a health check endpoint and specified it in the EC2 console? Something like:

[image: Health check snapshot]

*Note the port 80 and a valid route. You probably didn't set the port 3001 in your `nginx`/`apache` config*

In the rails app, create an action like so:

```
class HealthCheckController < ActionController::Base
  def ping
    head :ok
  end
end
```

and route:

```
get 'health_check/ping'
```

The AWS load balancer will ping his endpoint and if the response is a `200 OK` enough times (as per the `Healthy threshold`, it will deem the instance as "Healthy".

Comment: I did this, its failing. And I have set the port to 3001 too.

Comment: Did you set port 3001 in your nginx/apache config as well? Also what does your rails app logs say- is the health check request hitting your app?

Answer (score 1):

I see some issues with your ELB health check config. Right now, you have configured the health check to check an instance 10times every 24seconds before ELB will send requests. Hence, it takes

```
24seconds x 10 = 240secs # 4mins after reboot
```

assuming your Unicorn starts faster & doesn't die after its running, you should reduce the health check internal & healthy threshold.

- Reduce the Interval to 3-5seconds.
- Reduce Healthy threshold to 2-5times.

The above should help ELB to make instance "in service" faster.

This is assuming that your server config is properly setup to listen on `/healthcheck` port `3001` from external hosts. Please check your firewall/security groups/server config if that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the appserver's Security Group is allowing the ELB Security Group to access the health check endpoint at the port you've specified in the health check.

Comment: There is no issue with security groups. I checked.